# Find characteristic polynomial without representing matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, characteristic-polynomial

Consider the vector space of polynomials of degree 2 or lower with real coefficient $\mathbb{P}_2(\mathbb{R})$, operator $$T(f(x)) = f''(x)+f'(x)+f(0)x^2$$ and vector $g(x) = x$.

Determine the characteristic polynomial of $T$ without constructing a representation matrix of $T$.

My try: I determined the T-cyclic subspace $W$ generated by $g(x)$, which is $span\{x, 1, x^2\}$. I know a theorem that says the characteristic polynomial of $T_w$ is $$(-1)^k(a_0+a^1t+...+a_{k-1}t^{k-1}+t^k)$$. But how can find the coefficients $a_1,a_2,...$?

Thank you!

Comment: is $k=3$ here ?

Comment: $k$ is dimension of $W$

Comment: what is $W$ ? What is $\mathbb P_2(\mathbb R)$ ?

Comment: $W$ is the T-cyclic subspace generated by $g(x)$. ℙ2(ℝ) is vector space of polynomials of degree 2 or lower with real coefficient .

Comment: Don't we have $W=\mathbb P_2(\mathbb R)$  and $k = 3$ ? Can you write what is $W$ into the question please and also explain why you don't whant to use a representation matrix.

Comment: It is the question we cannot use representation matrix

Comment: Did you try to find the minimal polynomial for $T$ ?

Answer (score 1):

We compute $T^3$ by beginning with the square. Let $f \in \mathbb R_2[X]$. We note that $f''' = 0$. We have :

$$T^2(f) = 2 f(0) + f'' + 2 f(0)X + (f''(0) + f'(0))X^2 $$
and $$
T^3(f) =  2(f''(0) + f'(0)) + 2f(0)+2 (f''(0) + f'(0)) X + (2f(0) +f''(0))X^2$$
Using
$$f''(0) = f'' \quad \quad f = f(0) + f'(0) X + \frac{1}{2}f''(0) X^2 \quad \quad f' = f'(0) + f''(0) X$$ we obtain
$$
T^3(f) =  2f'' + 2f' + 2f + f(0) X^2$$

So $T^3 = 2T + 2\mathrm{id}$. It is not hard to see that $ X^3 - 2X - 2$ is in fact the minimum polynomial of $T$. It is then its characteristic polynomial ($k=3$).